# My client side app it says "500 (Internal Server Error)" otherwise other features work (login,register...)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

Hello guys I followed a fiverr clone tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csUM7yfiaMw&t=5679s&ab_channel=LamaDev, the issue is that I am facing an error on my application if anyone can help me when I try to add a gig (the model name) on my client side app it says "500 (Internal Server Error)" in the console otherwise other features work (login,register...) if anyone here can help me and thank you!
codes:

gig.controller.js:

```
import Gig from "../models/gig.model.js";
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const createGig = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.isSeller)
    return next(createError(403, "Only sellers can create a gig!"));

  const newGig = new Gig({
    userId: req.userId,
    ...req.body,
  });

  try {
    const savedGig = await newGig.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedGig);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
export const deleteGig = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const gig = await Gig.findById(req.params.id);
    if (gig.userId !== req.userId)
      return next(createError(403, "You can delete only your gig!"));

    await Gig.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).send("Gig has been deleted!");
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
export const getGig = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const gig = await Gig.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!gig) next(createError(404, "Gig not found!"));
    res.status(200).send(gig);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
export const getGigs = async (req, res, next) => {
  const q = req.query;
  const filters = {
    ...(q.userId && { userId: q.userId }),
    ...(q.cat && { cat: q.cat }),
    ...((q.min || q.max) && {
      price: {
        ...(q.min && { $gt: q.min }),
        ...(q.max && { $lt: q.max }),
      },
    }),
    ...(q.search && { title: { $regex: q.search, $options: "i" } }),
  };
  try {
    const gigs = await Gig.find(filters).sort({ [q.sort]: -1 });
    res.status(200).send(gigs);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

gig.model.js:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const GigSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    totalStars: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    starNumber: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    cat: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    cover: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    images: {
      type: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    shortTitle: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    shortDesc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    deliveryTime: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    revisionNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    features: {
      type: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    sales: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default mongoose.model("Gig", GigSchema);
```

gig.route.js:

```
 import express from "express";
    import {
      createGig,
      deleteGig,
      getGig,
      getGigs
    } from "../controllers/gig.controller.js";
    import { verifyToken } from "../middleware/jwt.js";
    
    const router = express.Router();
    
    router.post("/", verifyToken, createGig);
    router.delete("/:id", verifyToken, deleteGig);
    router.get("/single/:id", getGig);
    router.get("/", getGigs);
    
    export default router;

Add.jsx: 

import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";
import "./Add.scss";
import { gigReducer, INITIAL_STATE } from "../../reducers/gigReducer";
import upload from "../../utils/upload";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import newRequest from "../../utils/newRequest";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Add = () => {
  const [singleFile, setSingleFile] = useState(undefined);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(gigReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CHANGE_INPUT",
      payload: { name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value },
    });
  };
  const handleFeature = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_FEATURE",
      payload: e.target[0].value,
    });
    e.target[0].value = "";
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    setUploading(true);
    try {
      const cover = await upload(singleFile);

      const images = await Promise.all(
        [...files].map(async (file) => {
          const url = await upload(file);
          return url;
        })
      );
      setUploading(false);
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_IMAGES", payload: { cover, images } });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (gig) => {
      return newRequest.post("/gigs", gig);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(["myGigs"]);
    },
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    mutation.mutate(state);
    // navigate("/mygigs")
  };

  return (
    <div className="add">
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Add New Gig</h1>
        <div className="sections">
          <div className="info">
            <label htmlFor="">Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              placeholder="e.g. I will do something I'm really good at"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="">Category</label>
            <select name="cat" id="cat" onChange={handleChange}>
              <option value="design">Design</option>
              <option value="web">Web Development</option>
              <option value="animation">Animation</option>
              <option value="music">Music</option>
            </select>
            <div className="images">
              <div className="imagesInputs">
                <label htmlFor="">Cover Image</label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  onChange={(e) => setSingleFile(e.target.files[0])}
                />
                <label htmlFor="">Upload Images</label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  multiple
                  onChange={(e) => setFiles(e.target.files)}
                />
              </div>
              <button onClick={handleUpload}>
                {uploading ? "uploading" : "Upload"}
              </button>
            </div>
            <label htmlFor="">Description</label>
            <textarea
              name="desc"
              id=""
              placeholder="Brief descriptions to introduce your service to customers"
              cols="0"
              rows="16"
              onChange={handleChange}
            ></textarea>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Create</button>
          </div>
          <div className="details">
            <label htmlFor="">Service Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="shortTitle"
              placeholder="e.g. One-page web design"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="">Short Description</label>
            <textarea
              name="shortDesc"
              onChange={handleChange}
              id=""
              placeholder="Short description of your service"
              cols="30"
              rows="10"
            ></textarea>
            <label htmlFor="">Delivery Time (e.g. 3 days)</label>
            <input type="number" name="deliveryTime" onChange={handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="">Revision Number</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="revisionNumber"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="">Add Features</label>
            <form action="" className="add" onSubmit={handleFeature}>
              <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. page design" />
              <button type="submit">add</button>
            </form>
            <div className="addedFeatures">
              {state?.features?.map((f) => (
                <div className="item" key={f}>
                  <button
                    onClick={() =>
                      dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_FEATURE", payload: f })
                    }
                  >
                    {f}
                    <span>X</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <label htmlFor="">Price</label>
            <input type="number" onChange={handleChange} name="price" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

gigReducer.js:

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))?._id,
  title: "",
  cat: "",
  cover: "",
  images: [],
  desc: "",
  shortTitle: "",
  shortDesc: "",
  deliveryTime: 0,
  revisionNumber: 0,
  features: [],
  price: 0,
};

export const gigReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_INPUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value,
      };
    case "ADD_IMAGES":
      return {
        ...state,
        cover: action.payload.cover,
        images: action.payload.images,
      };
    case "ADD_FEATURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        features: [...state.features, action.payload],
      };
    case "REMOVE_FEATURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        features: state.features.filter(
          (feature) => feature !== action.payload
        ),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

App.jsx:

```
import "./app.scss";
import { createBrowserRouter, Outlet, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Gigs from "./pages/gigs/Gigs";
import Gig from "./pages/gig/Gig";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Add from "./pages/add/Add";
import Orders from "./pages/orders/Orders";
import Messages from "./pages/messages/Messages";
import Message from "./pages/message/Message";
import MyGigs from "./pages/myGigs/MyGigs";
import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Pay from "./pages/pay/Pay";
import Success from "./pages/success/Success";
function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  const Layout = () => {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <Navbar />
          <Outlet />
          <Footer />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <Home />,
        },
        {
          path: "/gigs",
          element: <Gigs />,
        },
        {
          path: "/myGigs",
          element: <MyGigs />,
        },
        {
          path: "/orders",
          element: <Orders />,
        },
        {
          path: "/messages",
          element: <Messages />,
        },
        {
          path: "/message/:id",
          element: <Message />,
        },
        {
          path: "/add",
          element: <Add />,
        },
        {
          path: "/gig/:id",
          element: <Gig />,
        },
        {
          path: "/register",
          element: <Register />,
        },
        {
          path: "/login",
          element: <Login />,
        },
        {
          path: "/pay/:id",
          element: <Pay />,
        },
        {
          path: "/success",
          element: <Success />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the internet connection or change the navigator it's maybe the used addons on your navigator that they are blocking the access